# How can I find the nearest matrix element value to a range in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I have a **3D matrix** and I need to find the nearest value to [0 to 1] range. For example, I have [-2.3 -1.87 -0.021 1.1 1.54] and -0.021 should be selected as it is the nearest value to the range.

EDITED: There would be zero or one value within the range. If there is one, that should be returned and if there is nothing, the nearest value should be returned

EDITED: This is the part of code which I'm trying to work correctly:

```
rt = zeros(size(audio_soundIntervals, 1), size(prtcpnt.audioAttention_ToM.sound_eventTime, 1), size(prtcpnt.audioAttention_ToM.sound_eventTime, 2));

for r = 1:size(prtcpnt.audioAttention_ToM.sound_eventTime, 1)
    for t = 1:size(prtcpnt.audioAttention_ToM.sound_eventTime, 2)
        for b = 1:size(audio_soundIntervals, 1)
       % here, I want to find the nearest element of audio_eventReshape(:, r, t) to the range [audio_soundIntervals(b, r, t), audio_soundIntervals(b, r, t) + 1]
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: @LuisMendo There would be zero or one value within the range. If there is one, that should be returned and if there is nothing, the nearest value should be returned.

Comment: Is this what you need? `x =  [-2.3 -1.87 -0.021 1.1 1.54]; r = [0 1]; [~, ind] = min(max([max(x(:).'-r(2), 0); max(r(1)-x(:).', 0)], [], 1)); result = x(ind);` (see the documentation of [`max`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/max.html) and of [`min`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/min.html) to see how it works)

Comment: @LuisMendo Thank you for the answer. This code always returns zero. That is not what I need to do.

Comment: Weird. In your example (just pasting my code as is) it gives `-0.021`

Comment: @LuisMendo My real matrix is 3D as I said in question and the example was just about a single row and column. Maybe this is the reason of the different outputs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The value nearest the center of the range is always the one you are looking for. I suggest you try out a few examples on paper to convince yourself of this.

The center of the range [a,b] is (b-a)/2. In your case this is 0.5.

Thus, finding the minimum of `abs(A-0.5)` will give you your answer. If `A` is a matrix, then `A(:)` is a vector you can apply your operation to. So we have:

```
[~,indx] = min(abs(A(:)-0.5));
```

Or more generally:

```
[~,indx] = min(abs(A(:)-(b-a)/2));
```

`indx` is the linear index into `A` for the element you are looking for, get the value with `A(indx)`.

Comment: Note that both `max()` and `min` support the `'all'` switch nowadays, allowing you ot do `min(A,'all')` rather than `min(A(:))`

Comment: @Adriaan Yes, that is true. But `min(A(:))` is still fewer characters to type. :p

Answer (score 1):

You can use this function to find the nearest value of `A` to the range `range`:

```
function out = near_range(A, range)
  [m1, idx1] = min(A - range(1), [], 'all', 'ComparisonMethod', 'abs');
  if abs(m1) >= diff(range)
    out = A(idx1);
    return
  end
  [m2, idx2] = min(A - range(2), [], 'all', 'ComparisonMethod', 'abs');
  if abs(m1) < abs(m2)
    out = A(idx1);
  else
    out = A(idx2);
  end
end
```

Usage:

```
result =  near_range([-2.3 -1.87 -0.021 1.1 1.54], [0 1]);
```

EDIT:

The `'ComparisonMethod'` option of function [min](https://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2021b/matlab/ref/min.html) is available starting from MATLAB R2021b. For older versions here is a way with [`dsearchn`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dsearchn.html):

```
[k, dst] = dsearchn(A(:), range(:));
result = A(k(1 + (diff(dst) < 0)));
```

EDIT2:

I packaged the second method as a function:

```
function out = near_range(A, range)
  [k, dst] = dsearchn(A(:), range(:));
  out = A(k(1 + (diff(dst) < 0)));
end
```

Usage:

```
rt(b, r, t) = near_range(audio_eventReshape(:, r, t), [audio_soundIntervals(b, r, t), audio_soundIntervals(b, r, t) + 1]);
```

Comment: I get this error: **Error using min: Options must be 'linear', 'omitnan', or 'includenan'.**

Comment: @yasaman.h I updated the answer!

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The first solution works in MATLAB 2021b. But I'm getting this error in MATLAB 2021a for the second solution: **Error using dsearchn: X and XI should have the same column dimension.** I think the inputs of `dsearchn` should be 2D and mien is 3D. Is that the problem?

Comment: No, the expression `A(:)` converts the array to a column vector.

Comment: @yasaman.h What do you mean by `3D matrix` ? Could you provide a small example of the matrix you have mentioned?

Comment: I've edited the question. Hope that makes the question more clear.

Comment: With the new condition that placed in the question I think the [method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70698386/6579744) proposed by @CrisLuengo is the best approach.